# Python - Replace function in exec and modules imported inside it

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec, python-import

I want to replace some builtin functions inside the code that I run with `exec`. It is possible by passing it as a dictionary entry in the second `exec` argument. But when I try to import a module inside the executed code, the functions are as in original bultins, when called inside imported module.

This is the example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
from inspect import cleandoc


def new_print(val):
    print('Hello', val)

code_inner = cleandoc("""
    def bar():
        print('Inner')
""")

with open('inner.py', 'w') as f:
    f.write(code_inner)

code_outer = cleandoc("""
    import inner
    print('Outer')
    inner.bar()
""")

exec(code_outer, {'print': new_print}, {})
```

This is the response that I receive:

```
Hello Outer
 Inner
```

And this is what I would like to have:

```
Hello Outer
Hello Inner
```

Is there any way to pass new globals, or builtins, or maybe variable list to the module beeing imported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's quite what you want, but passing a dictionary parameter to the function and updating its modules globals works.

```
code_inner = cleandoc("""
    def bar(d):
        globals().update(d)
        print('Inner')
""")


code_outer = cleandoc("""
    import inner
    print('Outer')
    inner.bar({'print': print})
""")
```

Alternatively, without modification of the bar function you can pass its module a global like so:

```
code_outer = cleandoc("""
    import inner
    inner.print = print
    print('Outer')
    inner.bar()
""")
```